# Python float print in real time

Tags: python

Is there any way to print the numbers in real times instead of printing them one by one? I have 6 different countries

```
china = 1399746872
india = 1368138206
USA = 327826334
Japan = 12649000
Russia = 146804372
Sweden = 10379295
```

I change this numbers in the script but how do I print them so I see them change?

!EDITED!

I want to kind of overwrite this list everytime it prints so I see the numbers go up

```
Countries = []
china = 1399746872
india = 1368138206
USA = 327826334
Japan = 12649000
Russia = 146804372
Sweden = 10379295

Countries.append(china)
Countries.append(india)
Countries.append(USA)
Countries.append(Japan)
Countries.append(Russia)
Countries.append(Sweden)

print(Countries)
```

Comment: You mean you want to overwrite old values with new ones on some kind of display?

Comment: ```print(china, india, USA, Japan, Russia, Sweden)``` You mean this?

Comment: @ScottHunter yes that is right

Comment: That's not how `print` works.

Comment: @ScottHunter why do you say that? If you run `print(china, india, USA, Japan, Russia, Sweden)`, the output is `1399746872 1368138206 327826334 12649000 146804372 10379295`. Sure, the name of each country isn't printed out, but that's an easy fix. But the point is that it works fine that way, so it's not clear why you would say that "that's now how `print` works".

Comment: @ScottHunter Yeah I know but is there some other way I can do it then?

Comment: @RandomDavis: Read the earlier comments.

Comment: There are *lots* of ways, but you need some mechanism to make a display you can overwrite; `tkinter`, for example.

Comment: Ok think I know what to do know

Comment: Maybe you just wanna use a debugger, or even simpler solutions such as printing to stdou many times with `print(whatever, end="\n", flush=True)`, which will overwrite the console line.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `os.system("cls")` to clear the console.

I made a little demo:

```py
import time, sys, json, os
from random import randint

vals = {
    "china": 1399746872,
    "india": 1368138206,
    "USA": 327826334,
    "Japan": 12649000,
    "Russia": 146804372,
    "Sweden": 10379295
}

for _ in range(100):
    # clear console
    os.system("cls")   
    # print values     
    [print(f"{k}: {v}") for k, v in vals.items()]
    # renew values with random generated integers
    vals = {k:randint(0, 1000000) for k in vals}
    # sleep 5s
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Where I generate the random values would be where you fetch the new ones ;)